# Getting value from a SimpleXMLElement object

Tags: php, arrays, object, simplexml

I have

```
$number[0]
```

which is a object(SimpleXMLElement) type.

It has just one element.

The element has this pair 
0 -- 9

9 is a string I need to have in a variable.

Comment: Post the output from `print_r($number);`

Comment: "The element has this pair 0 -- 9" what do you mean by this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to access anything in your `SimpleXMLElement`, you will have to access it like an object. i.e

```
$value = $xml->foo->bar->baz;
```

This is desribed in more detail at [the official documentation for SimpleXML](https://www.php.net/manual/en/simplexml.examples-basic.php)