# accessing a SimpleXMLElement array

Tags: php, xml, simplexml

I have:

```
$a = new SimpleXMLElement($myString);
```

Where $a contains:

```
$a
: object(SimpleXMLElement) = 
  HEADER: object(SimpleXMLElement) = 
    LOG: object(SimpleXMLElement) = 
    PARAMS: object(SimpleXMLElement) = 
  CONTENT: object(SimpleXMLElement) = 
    LOT: object(SimpleXMLElement) = 
      DEGREES: object(SimpleXMLElement) = 
        @attributes: array = 
          value: string = 30
```

This

```
 $a->CONTENT->LOT->DEGREE[@value];
```

Gets me:

```
: object(SimpleXMLElement) = 
  0: string = 30
```

How can I get 30?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Getting value from a SimpleXMLElement object](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8230894/getting-value-from-a-simplexmlelement-object) and lots of others.

Comment: none of what I've seen have an array in it ..

Comment: Now there's no XPath any more. Please add the XML that produces this output, I guess your XPath query was wrong.

Comment: You should paste the XML and the plain result of `print_r($a)` in your question instead of that format you're using it right now. Have you tried `$a->CONTENT->LOT->DEGREE[@value][0]` or `(string) $a->CONTENT->LOT->DEGREE[@value]`?

Comment: Please, Rolando, post your comment as an answer so I can accept it .. it was (string) what I was missing. Thanks a million!!!

Comment: There's also a typo: `DEGREE` vs. `DEGREES`.